# Domain of Domain? Well-Defined-ness of Domain?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

So taking a set-theoretic definition of a function f from set $A$ to $B$, we can say that it's a subset of $A\times B$. But then I was thinking about domain; after call we can write it as $domain(f) = A$, so in a way, domain behaves like a function. But then I run into some... really serious issues. Namely, consider $domain(domain)$. Well, domain can take any function, so it can take any set that can be written as $A\times B$ for some A and B. But then, if for example, we allow B to be {{}}, then A can just be *any* set. But then $domain(domain)\supseteq S\times B$, where S is the set of all sets... which is a logically inconsistent construction.

So my question(s) is,
1) If domain isn't a function, then what is it? What can capture its intuitive usage of mapping functions onto sets?
2) Or is there a way of generalizing functions to fit what domain does (i.e. map all functions onto sets)?

Comment: I think you can interpret "domain" as a function on sets: the domain of set $X$ is the set $\left\{ a\mid\exists b\langle a,b\rangle\in X\right\}$. If e.g. $X$ does not contain any ordered pairs then its domain is empty.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points here:

1. Yes, the $\operatorname{dom}$ is a function on any relation. It returns the unique set which is the domain of the relation (not just a function).
2. Since not every set is a set of ordered pairs, not every set is a relation, and not every set has a domain. You can either decide that $\operatorname{dom}$ is only defined for sets whose elements are all ordered pairs, or you can define $\operatorname{dom}(A)=\{x\mid\exists y(\langle x,y\rangle\in A)\}$. In that case the $\operatorname{dom}$ function gives you the $\varnothing$ for sets without any ordered pairs, or some set which is the domain of the relation made of all the ordered pairs which are in $A$.

Comment: But then, considering your 2nd point, what would the dom(dom) be? (since, as you note in the 1st point, dom is a function (and therefore a relation) on relations, namely, it's a relation, so dom should be defined on it)

Comment: It will be something. If the domain of $f$ is itself a set of ordered pairs, it will be the domain of that, and if that domain is a set of ordered pairs, then its domain will be the domain of that. And so on. I'm not sure what sort of answer you expect. It would be a set.